# Getting a reference to a Jersey REST resource method from the URL

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm doing some performance testing, and I want to be able to call a resource method without going through the network. I already have a framework for generating URLs, and I'd like to be able to reuse it.

For example, given the URL: www.example.com:8080/resource/method, I want to get a reference to the resource method that it calls, so that I can run it without making a network-level HTTP request. I.e., in the example below, I want to use the URL "www.frimastudio.com:8080/time" to get a reference to the method getServerTime() that I can then call directly.

Does Jersey (or something else?) provide a way to do this, or do I have to import the specific Resource class I want to call, instantiate it, etc.? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, just instantiate your Resource Class and call the Method. You cant call the method more directly and comfortable than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes jersey is RESTful API that allow routes configuration (only with annotations)

Example :

```
package com.frimastudio.webservice.controller.route;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.frimastudio.webservice.controller.representation.Time;

@Path("/time")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TimeResource
{

    public TimeResource()
    {
    }

    @GET
    public Time getServerDate()
    {
        return new Time(new DateTime());
    }

}
```

with Time being a Jackson representation :

```
package com.frimastudio.webservice.controller.representation;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Time
{
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty
    private String date;

    public Time()
    {
        // Jackson deserialization
    }

    public Time(String date)
    {
        super();
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Time(DateTime date)
    {
        super();
        this.date = date.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that I wasn't clear enough in my question. I already have resource methods defined and all. I'm doing performance testing from an external class, and I have the URL (www.frimastudio.com:8080/time from your example). I know Jersey can be used (via the WebResource) to throw HTTP requests at that URL. I want to use that URL to get a reference to the getServerDate() method, so I can call it directly, without going through the network.

Comment: If you want to perform a load testing script, you should call directly you uri as a client would do. If you really want to bypass http server and call your function, you should use another communication service such as websocket.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible, based on looking at the Jersey code.  The lookup is performed by `HttpMethodRule.Matcher`, which is a private class used only to implement `HttpMethodRule.accept`.

Seems to me everything in `accept` up to `if (s == MatchStatus.MATCH) {` could be pulled into its own method and exposed to the user.